# iOS AFNetworking + SSL Can't do HTTPS

Tags: ios, ssl, https, afnetworking

I have a valid SSL certificate, and I'm trying to do some https requests, but it seems AFNetworking has some kind of problem with https, I can't do requests, but if I add this policy:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    manager.securityPolicy = securityPolic;
```

To my manager, my requests start to work. So I have 2 questions, there is no workaround without setting the policy to accept invalid ssl? Also is this method secure for valid ssl certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your third party certs are fully trusted? Try using an app called SSL Detective to make sure that the entire chain is trusted (no red components). Your problem might be your certificate chain.

In my implementation, setting the policy to accept invalid certs is only allowed during debug builds and then only valid certs allowed during production builds.